# Gitlab Runner fails creating android build using the newer yml format

Tags: android, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using gitlab runner and have linked the runner correctly following the quick start guides. But there is some issue in yml file. AFAIK the issue lies somewhere in docker image. But dont know what the steps to debug and fix it should be. The docker images are listed in logs below. The builds tools and adt are all there in beevelop/android.

```
# ANDROID_HOME should be setup in env
before_script:
    - pwd
    - chmod +x ./gradlew

dev:
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

Gitlab Runner log:

```
gitlab-ci-multi-runner 0.7.2 (998cf5d)
Using Docker executor with image beevelop/android ...
Pulling docker image gitlab/gitlab-runner:build ...
Pulling docker image beevelop/android:latest ...

Running on runner-553c2779-project-109852-concurrent-0 via RC900...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/rcmobile/bemol'...
Checking out bcd208a9 as master...
Note: checking out 'bcd208a9b4604905f2253511ed32410443428047'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at bcd208a... Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/master'

bash: line 19: cd: /builds/rcmobile/bemol: No such file or directory

ERROR: Build failed with: exit code 1
```

Comment: This post, written by an Android developer of Snapchat, might help you: https://about.gitlab.com/2016/11/30/setting-up-gitlab-ci-for-android-projects/. He explains how to build and test an Android app with GitLab CI, gives the code you need for .gitlab-ci.yml and break it into parts, explained one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue when I was running the Gitlab runner client on a Windows box configured with the 'docker' executor.  It appears that when the runner was setting up the cache container, it was escaping the Windows backslash for directories (e.g. \builds\development\project).  Then when it actually went to use the directory, it was using the UNIX forward slash (e.g. /builds/development/project), resulting in the "No such file or directory" error.  From your log output I cannot tell if this is the same situation.

I could not figure out how to get the cache container to use the correct directory.  Instead, I solved the issue by using the Gitlab runner docker client, following some of the documentation outlined here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/install/docker.md

Comment: Unfortunately, I am already docker. Used the same install script as u pointed out.